# Why do I get an exception when trying to create a new Console?

Tags: java, scjp

```
import java.io.*;

public class Talk {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Console c = new Console();
        String pw;
        System.out.print("password: ");
        pw = c.readLine();
        System.out.println("got " + pw);
    }
}
```

Please explain to me this compiler exception at console

> java:5: error: Console() has private access in Console Console c = new Console(); 
>                                                                               ^ 1 error

Comment: well, that's an obvious and very clear error. If you know what you should know for the exam you should know why that is an error, even if you may not know what exact code you would use to prevent that error.

Comment: For your own good: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html. You'll notice that there's no public constructor for `Console`.

Answer (score 3):

The `Console` class is obviously not meant to be instantiated directly. You are supposed to use `System.console` instead:

> If this virtual machine has a console then it is represented by a
>   unique instance of this class which can be obtained by invoking the
>   System.console() method. If no console device is available then an
>   invocation of that method will return null.

[See the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Console.html).

Comment: I also think that , Console c =System.console(); should replace Console c = new Console();